# Array to Active Record Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I want to show in a view the tasks for a day in concrete (today). these tasks have an estimated time that must sum 6 hours per day.

in the model I have this method:

```
def self.tasks_for_today
  total_time = 0
  r = Array.new
  all(:conditions => "finished = 0").each do | t |
    total_time += t.estimated_time
    r << t if total_time <= 6
  end  
  r 
end
```

and works fine, but I need the "r" variable to be a instance of a Tasks model, not a instance of Array class...

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you mean? tasks_for_today should (and does) return an array of Tasks.  You want a collection of tasks, not a singular task.  Can you clarify exactly how this differs from what you want?

Comment: Yes, tasks_for_today return an Array of Tasks, but I want to return it as an instance of ActiveRecord, just like the find method...

Comment: #find returns a collection of instances actually, not an instance.  I think that's why we're confused.

Comment: I assume you want to do something later with this, like Tasks.tasks_for_today.first, or something like that? - I've always struggled with the best way to do that.

Comment: Yes, later I execute Task.task_for_today.each do | t | ... end. that method must return a set of tasks that together sum a total of 6 hours...

Comment: #first was a bad example, but perhaps another scope or something is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will return an array of tasks and Task.all also returns an array of tasks. Try it:

```
>> Task.all.class
=> Array
```

And with any array you can do things like:

```
t.first
t.each {|a| ... }
```

What you exactly want to do with your result?

Answer (score 0):

One refactor you might do already is to use a [named_scoped](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) for your unfinished tasks:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :unfinished, :conditions => {:finished => false}
end
```

You don't really want to return an instance (an instance means just one task).

You might be able to order your tasks, [get a running sum](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-running-totals.html), and then return only the tasks that have a running sum below 6.  I have to think about it more, but if you do it that way, you'll end up using [find_by_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002557) and SQL magic provided by your DB engine of choice.

Comment: Hi, i want to select a set of tasks that together sum a total of 6 hours... the method that I write does that, but return an instance of Array and I need to be Activerecord, just like Model.all

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use a named_scope somehow, because you can keep scoping it and use it just like ActiveRecord (ex. Tasks.unfinished.older_than(3.days))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it was my mistake, the method does what I want...

Here is the final code:

```
def self.tasks_for_today
  total_time = 0
  r = Array.new
  all(:conditions => "finished = 0").each do | t |
    total_time += t.estimated_time
    total_time <= 6 ? r << t : break
  end
  r
end
```